# Delete line in powershell file

Tags: powershell, contains

I have a file with the following lines

```
Servicetag 
P4M8K82 
P4M8l582  
O5M8K82
```

I wish I had the serial numbers only and not the name `ServiceTag`. 
I would like: Browse the .csv file if the line contains `SerivceTag` then you don't get the value and copy the rest.

As a result, I wish I had:

```
P4M8K82 
P4M8l582  
O5M8K82
```

Do you think it's possible?

Comment: Is that a CSV file or TXT file?

Comment: If its a CSV, this works for you? `$Content = Import-Csv myfile.csv` 
`if ($Content.Servicetag) {$Content.Servicetag}`

Comment: Yes it's in .csv 
it would be more in the -contains and not to delete the first line. 
To ensure "security" if the servicetag comes to put it in the middle of the servicetags.

Comment: @Smarty13 is `ServiceTag` always expected to be the first line of the file?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a CSV header, you can just skip first line:

```
#demo file
@"
Servicetag 
P4M8K82 
P4M8l582  
O5M8K82  
"@ | out-file Test.csv

#solution to get items
cat test.csv | select -Skip 1

#or write them to file
cat test.csv | select -Skip 1 | Out-file output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I use this method too. What I'm looking for if you can help me, it would be to browse the .csv file and say what contains "Servicetag" you don't copy it to the new .CSV file. I don't know if I was clear.

Answer (score 0):

Although not really clear what you are asking, the below line will read the file as string array and write out a new file with all lines containing 'ServiceTag' removed:

```
Get-Content -Path 'TheOriginalFile'| Where-Object { $_ -notmatch 'ServiceTag' } | Set-Content -Path 'TheNewFile'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input file looks like a CSV File with only one field.  When there is only one field, there aren't any separating commas.  Servicetag is not a data entry.  It's the name of the field, also known as a header.

Try the following:

```
Import-Csv Test.csv | Format-Table
```

The result is a table with just one column header.  If you do something like:

```
$testdata = Import-Csv Test.csv
```

now your data is imported in a form suitable for processing.